# Consuming require() errors in web3.js client

Tags: solidity, web3js, error

Using `require` helps in validating user inputs before an action can be taken. However, it seems not many options exist to handle the scenario when `require` indeed returns `false`. The example mentioned in this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/24973/3137) uses Events that are fired after testing an `if` condition. This [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30027/3137) bluntly says that it is not possible to handle `revert` (even though the question was about `require`) from the front-end.

So, is it possible to consume a `require` `false` outcome at all? Or, can it be piped into an Event that can be consumed in a `web3.js` client?

Comment: From a `web3,js` client, you can very easily invoke and handle a function-call which triggers `require(<false condition>)`, if that's what you mean. I do that all the time (as part of testing and verification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require / assert / revert everything that was done or would be done in the function is rolled back, that includes Events as well.

So, no, if a require / revert / assert happens there's no way to inform or return anything useful to handle the error.

As I mentioned in another similar question, you will need to check for this potential errors client-side as well so you can prevent the contract from reaching such a state.
(E. G.: if a function requires that msg.sender == owner, in the front-end if the logged user is not the owner, disable/hide the button that calls this contract function)

Comment: Ok. Suppose a contract depended on another contract that had a `require` failure. This cannot be handled by front end. How does one deal with such a scenario?

Comment: You just can't. The execution will fail and the user will not know why. The best you can do is to explain as well as possible under what conditions a certain function might fail.

Answer (score 2):

Error reason strings for revert and require has been introduced in solidity 0.4.22. You can define the reason of `revert` and `require`. With some bug fixes, latest version of solidity is 0.4.23.

For more details: https://medium.com/secureblocks/solidity-0-4-22-enhancements-94d2b9b8b6fe

Comment: How can you access these errors from web3 though?

Comment: @Makaronodentro this is not posssible yet, work is in progress for this. Although on Remix you can see the error reason string.

Comment: is it possible to access there errors from web3 now? @Aniket

Comment: @deju It is supported by truffle too but web3 looks to support it in 1.0 stable release targetting on 30th june. Follow this for updates: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1707